# jQuery plugin to load a full-page view window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, plugin

I have been writing a lot of jQuery plugins lately, but I don't really know if what I am doing is any good. Here is one of my most recent plugins. It allows the user to add a data attribute to any class and load a full page view window (which is written to the body on render) to e.g. open a menu on mobile or read large pieces of text without taking up the entire page (scrolling on a product page for example):

```
(function ($) {
    var jelm = $('.js-full-page-view');

    var methods = {
        init: function () {
            jelm.each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id'),
                    title = ($(this).data('caFullPageTitle')) ? $(this).data('caFullPageTitle') : '',
                    content = (!$(this).data('caSingle')) ? $(this).html() : '',
                    action_container = ($(this).data('caActionContainer')) ? $(this).data('caActionContainer') : '',
                    indented_content = ($(this).data('caNoIndentedContent')) ? '' : 'full-page-view--indented-content',
                    bottom_action_container = '';

                if ($(this).data('caBottomActionContainer')) {
                    bottom_action_container = '<div class="full-page-view--footer-bar">' + $(this).data('caBottomActionContainer') + '</div>';
                }

                $('body').append(
                    '<div class="full-page-view js-full-page-view" id="fp_' + id
                    + '"><div class="full-page-view--main-bar"><div class="full-page-view--action-container"><button class="full-page-view--action js-full-page-view-close"><svg class="icon-svg alt-flip"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg></button></div><div class="full-page-view--title">' + title
                    + '</div><div class="full-page-view--action-container">' + action_container + '</div></div><div class="full-page-view--scroll-pane full-page-view--content ' + indented_content + '">' + content
                    + '</div>' + bottom_action_container + '</div>');
            });
            methods.bind();
        },
        bind: function () {
            $('.js-full-page-view-open').on('click', function () {
                var open_elm = ($(this).data('caTarget')) ? $("#" + $(this).data('caTarget')) : $(this).closest('.js-full-page-view');
                if (methods.responsive_check(open_elm)) {
                    methods.open('#fp_' + open_elm.attr('id'));
                }
            });

            $('.js-full-page-view-close').on('click', function () {
                var close_elm = ($(this).data('caTarget')) ? $(this).data('caTarget') : $(this).closest('.js-full-page-view');
                methods.close('#' + close_elm.attr('id'));
            });
        },
        close: function (selector) {
            $(selector).removeClass('active').ceScrollLock('body', 'rm');
            if (methods.single_check('#' + selector.substring(4))) {
                var focus = $(selector + ' .full-page-view--content');
                var content = $(focus).html();
                $('#' + selector.substring(4) + ' .full-page-view--content-placeholder').append(content);
                focus.empty();
            }
        },
        open: function (selector) {
            $(selector).addClass('active');
            setTimeout(function() {$(selector).ceScrollLock('body', 'add');}, 200);
            if (methods.single_check('#' + selector.substring(4))) {
                var focus = $('#' + selector.substring(4) + ' .full-page-view--content-placeholder');
                var content = $(focus).html();
                $(selector + ' .full-page-view--content').append(content);
                focus.empty();
            }
        },
        responsive_check: function (selector) {
            return $.fn.getRealWidth() <= $(selector).data('caResponsiveMax');
        },
        responsive_resize: function () {
            $('.js-full-page-view.active').each(function() {
                if (!methods.responsive_check('#' + $(this).attr('id').substring(3))) {
                    methods.close('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
                }
            });
        },
        single_check: function (elem) {
            return !!$(elem).data('caSingle');
        }
    };

    $.fn.ceFullPageView = function (method) {
        return $(this).each(function (i, elm) {
            var errors = {};

            if (methods[method]) {
                return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                $.error('fullpageview: method ' + method + ' does not exist');
            }
        });
    };
    
    if ($(document).ready()) {
        $('.js-full-page-view').ceFullPageView();

        $('.js-full-page-view-open').on('click', function () {
            $(this).ceFullPageView('bind');
        });
        $('.js-full-page-view-close').on('click', function () {
            $(this).ceFullPageView('bind');
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $(this).ceFullPageView('responsive_resize');
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And the supportive functions

```
(function (_, $) {
    var methods = {
        rm: function () {
            $('body').removeClass('is-non-scrollable-fixed');
        },
        add: function() {
            $('body').addClass('is-non-scrollable-fixed');
        }
    };

    $.fn.ceScrollLock = function (selector, method) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, arguments);
    };

    $.fn.ceIsIE = function (userAgent) {
        userAgent = userAgent || navigator.userAgent;
        return userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("Edge/") > -1;
    };

    $.fn.getRealWidth = function () {
        var outer = $('<div>').css({visibility: 'hidden', width: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}).appendTo('body'),
            widthWithScroll = $('<div>').css({width: '100%'}).appendTo(outer).outerWidth();
        outer.remove();
        var scrollBarWidth = 100 - widthWithScroll;

        if ($.fn.ceIsIE) {
            return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        }

        if ($('.is-non-scrollable-fixed').length) {
            return $('body').width();
        } else {
            return $('body').width() + scrollBarWidth;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="js-full-page-view" data-ca-single="true" data-ca-responsive-max="667" data-ca-full-page-title="{sl 'filter'}" id="full_page_product_filter">
    <div class="full-page-view--content-placeholder"> 
        Any HTML content
    <div>
</div>
```

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML and supportive  js functions. I tried updating the fiddle cited in my answer but it didn’t work. I noticed the IiFE for the supportive functions passes one argument (I.e. `jQuery`) while the function definition expects two two parameters (I.e. `_, $`). Is underscore or old ash required for it to work? I don’t actually see `_` used within the function...

Answer (score 1):

### Feedback

Overall the code seems to be architected acceptably (though see the first review point below about the DOM-ready code). Some of the HTML generation seems complex - perhaps using a template system (e.g. using a [template  `<script>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912608/1575353)) would be a good way to abstract out that markup. I tried [making a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samonela/ac6unxgf/) to use the plugin but without knowing what all HTML elements were required I wasn't able to really get it running as expected. Feel free to fork my fiddle, add requisite HTML elements and [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/202682/edit) your post to contain a link to such a fiddle.

### Review points

#### DOM-ready code

Towards the end of the code I see this:

> ```
> if ($(document).ready()) {
>       $('.js-full-page-view').ceFullPageView();
> ```

I honestly haven't seen much code like that before. [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) returns a [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object. So that would be similar to the following:

```
if({"0": {"location": {"replace": function() {}} /* ... */}}) {
```

And any object used as an expression in a conditional statement evaluates to a truthy value<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)</sup>. Typically, the code to be evaluated when the DOM is ready is passed in a callback function - like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-full-page-view').ceFullPageView();
    $('.js-full-page-view-open').on('click', function () {
        $(this).ceFullPageView('bind');
    });
    $('.js-full-page-view-close').on('click', function () {
        $(this).ceFullPageView('bind');
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(this).ceFullPageView('responsive_resize');
    });
});
```

But the second line of the code does a DOM lookup:

> ```
> (function ($) {
>     var jelm = $('.js-full-page-view');
> ```

So perhaps the whole code should be wrapped in a callback when the DOM is ready. You didn't mention which version of jQuery is used/supported, but presuming it is 3.0 or higher (correct me if that is incorrect) the form `$(document).ready()` is deprecated<sup>[2](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup> and the only supported form is `$(handler)` so the code could be updated like below. Additionally, there is a shortcut method for `.on('click'` - [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click).

```
$(function() {
    var jelm = $('.js-full-page-view');

    var methds = {
        /** methods **/
    };

    $.fn.ceFullPageView = function (method) {
        return $(this).each(function (i, elm) {
            /** skipped for brevity **/
        });
    }

    $('.js-full-page-view').ceFullPageView();

    $('.js-full-page-view-open').click(function () {
        $(this).ceFullPageView('bind');
    });
    $('.js-full-page-view-close').click(function () {
        $(this).ceFullPageView('bind');
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(this).ceFullPageView('responsive_resize');
    });

});
```

#### DOM lookups

I see many DOM lookups throughout but the selectors differ a bit so while I normally recommend those be cached in a variable, I don't see many that are redundant and it might not be feasible given the dynamic nature of the code. But `jelm` could be used in the first line of the code currently called after `$(document).ready()`:

> ```
> $('.js-full-page-view').ceFullPageView();
> ```

Can be changed to:

```
jelm.ceFullPageView();
```

#### function `ceScrollLock()`?

I am not familiar with that function, nor could I find any webpages online (besides this one and [an untitled paste on pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/LdqBSaQV) which I presume is yours) that contain that string. Where is it defined?

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>http://api.jquery.com/ready/</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added the HTML and other JS functions.